# How do I disable the sign up link for the aws amplify angular authenticator?

Tags: angular, aws-amplify

I'm using the amplify-authenticator component from the aws-amplify/ui-angular library to enable authentication for my app. I'm trying to figure out how to disable the "Create Account" link on the front end and I can't seem to find anything in the documentation or online. It's possible I'm just missing the documentation, but does anyone know how to remove the sign up functionality from the angular amplify authenticator?

Component

```
<amplify-authenticator usernameAlias="email">
  <amplify-sign-in slot="sign-in" hide-sign-up="true"></amplify-sign-in>
</amplify-authenticator>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AmplifyAuthenticatorModule } from '@aws-amplify/ui-angular';


import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    AmplifyAuthenticatorModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Getting Error:

```
'amplify-sign-in' is not a known element:
1. If 'amplify-sign-in' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'amplify-sign-in' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

13   <amplify-sign-in slot="sign-in" hide-sign-up="true"></amplify-sign-in>
     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  src/app/app.component.ts:7:16
    7   templateUrl: './app.component.html',
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component AppComponent.
```

Comment: Have you tried this https://ui.docs.amplify.aws/angular/connected-components/authenticator/configuration#hide-sign-up

Answer (score 0):

```
<amplify-authenticator [hideSignUp]="true">
```

This removes the sign-up functionality.